# Any better way to convert float image to integer image?

Tags: type-conversion, dm-script

all:
I'm using the following code to convert the rotated image (float image) to integer image. I'm not sure whether it's the best way. If there is any better way, please let me know.

```
Image img := GetFrontImage()
Number rot_angle_rad = 30/(180/pi())
Image rotate_img = img.Rotate(rot_angle_rad)
Number sx, sy
rotate_img.GetSize(sx, sy)
Image inte_img := IntegerImage("tempImage", 2, 0, sx, sy)
inte_img = rotate_img
inte_img.ShowImage()
```

Comment: In line#3 you're COPYING data. You create an image on the right. Then you create a matching container (float type) on the left, and then you are copying values.
Instead, you could just assign a variables to the result, if you use `:=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific `ConvertTo` methods that do that in-place.
Fresh from the F1 help documentation:

[image]

```
Number rot_angle_rad = 30/(180/pi())
Image img := GetFrontImage()
Image int_img := img.Rotate(rot_angle_rad)
int_img.ConvertToLong()
int_img.ShowImage()
```